# When should I use "there" and "their"?

Tags: word-usage, homophones

For example, in the following sentences, in which ones should I use *there*, and not *their*?

> __*_*_ house is beautiful.
>   ***_*__*_*** are lots of skyscrapers in Dubai.

Comment: Don't forget they're ;)

Comment: I think it's important that you recognize the part of speech they belong to. Once that's sorted, really, you can't go wrong.

Comment: How has this question got 14 votes? It's a pretty mediocre question (if I don't use the term _dumb_).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In grammatical terms, *their* is a possessive determiner, just like *my, your, his, her, its* and *our*. It indicates that what is described in the following noun phrase belongs to, or is in some other way associated with, the person or thing to which the possessive determiner refers. Just as *my car* is a car that belongs to me, so *their house* is a house that belongs to them.

*There* is a word with many uses. In your example, *There are lots of skyscrapers in Dubai*, it is what is sometimes called a ‘dummy subject’. It would be grammatical to say *Lots of skyscrapers are in Dubai*, but, generally, we don’t. We use *there are* (or *there is*) where French uses *il est* or *il y a*, German uses *es ist, es sind* or *es gibt* and Spanish uses *hay*.

Comment: Japanese uses: ある　for "there are"/"there is" which literally means "to exist".

Answer (score 10):

*Their* means *belonging to them*, while *there* is a place or a "dummy subject." In your examples, you would say:

> *Their* house is beautiful.
>
> *There* are lots of skyscrapers in Dubai.

In the second example, *there* is a "dummy subject." In the following example, it is a place:

> They are in the skyscraper over *there*.